# Using Lambda in Android Studio (in a Java project)

Tags: java, android, maven, lambda

I have tried to add a Java project to my Android project with using artifact build and making JAR file from Java project:

[image]

But, now when I try to compile the project it has an error with lambda:

[image]

I have added Jack plugin, I'm using Java 8 on my project and I checked that all the classes that the error says missed are in JAR project. An example of the error in a file:

```
public UInteger getMaxResponseMessageSize() { return _maxResponseMessageSize; }

public DateTime getClientConnectionTime() { return _clientConnectionTime; }
```

These two lines have the error (and many other lines like this).

Comment: jack is discontinued

Comment: how can I fix that?